# Spring MVC @Autowired field is null

Tags: java, spring

I am learing Spring MVC and creating project using CRUD and In my web application i want to create a new Player in form and add it from a Team class to a List which is in the PlayersDAO class , but when i do it it returns a message "class is null" , i found an answer for the similar problem but it did not help me

here are the parts of my code:

```
@Component
public class PlayersDAO {

    private static int PLAYER_ID;
    private static List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
    
}
```

and this is my Team class where I am using this component

```
@Component
public class Team {
    @Autowired
    private PlayersDAO playersDAO;
    private List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addPlayer(Player player) {
        players.add(player);
        if (playersDAO != null) {
            playersDAO.addPlayer(player);
        } else {
            System.out.println("class of null");
        }
    }
    
}
```

and as i read the cause can be also using a "new" operator while creating an instances of that class, in other class i created a new instance of class Team if it is the reason how can i solve it ( I need a new object of that class to ) ?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/teams")
public class TeamsController {
    @GetMapping("/new")
    public String createTeam(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("team",new Team());
        return "/teams/create";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Autowired only takes effect when the object is handled by the spring context. As you said, the problem is that you created an object using the 'new' operator, this object will be not handled by spring.
You have to use the application context. Also, the @Component default scope is singleton, add the annotation @Scope("prototype") to your Team component if you want to get a new object every time you call getBean().

Check if this code helps you.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/teams")
public class TeamsController {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    @GetMapping("/new")
    public String createTeam(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("team",appContext.getBean(Team.class));
        return "/teams/create";
    }
}
```